# How do I have my iPhone rotate the homescreen?

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak

The iPad has the cool feature of being able to rotate the home screen (screens) with apps on them, I was wondering if this is possible for the iPhone's as well?  If so, how do I do this.  My iPhone is Jailbroken so using a Cydia or equilvalent app is possible.  I'm also looking to auto rotate the lock screeen as well.

Comment: Personally, I find the rotation aspect of the iPad's homescreen to be a pretty bad feature, since it screws up the location of my (very) carefully arranged icons. I have had to resort to additional hacks to get a square grid (7x7, in my case) to ensure that when rotated, the icons are always still in the same position. Something to think about when you try SBRotator -- I suggest keeping your homescreen layout square (4x4, 5x5, etc.).

Comment: just one question: why?

Comment: @Cawas: Because there are times, like now where I'm switching from one landscaping typing situation to another. I have a Bluetooth keyboard that I use and a few apps that I use as well with it. I was hoping to have a way that landscape would be kept throughout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SBRotator](http://cydia.xsellize.com/) is a bit awful, but it works.

Comment: It works, but I dislike the implementation of the rotating homescreen on the iPad, so I gave up on it on my iPhone. If Apple had done it *right* (keeping icons in the right spot), I wouldn't dislike that feature so much.

Comment: I did warn you! But hey, WWDC is tomorrow with iOS5 preview. Maybe we'll get some screen rotation too.

Comment: Oh, so can't wait until the iOS5 preview... so many possibilities. :-)

Comment: Based on WWDC keynote as well as beta preview, no home screen rotation for iPhones on iOS5 that I can see. SBRotator still the only option, albeit not ideal.

Comment: While this does work, it's terrible in implementation.  However, it is currently the only option.